# The results of the program in automatic mode and in debug mode are different

Tags: c#, debugging, properties, project

When I doing debug mode in my project I can see true results and I'm sure, that it's right code here. But when I start application not in debug mode - I get wrong results!

Also, when I tired to work in debug mode, I press "continue" button, and what do I see? Program starts to get wrong results after my debugging!

Can you tell me, what is going on!? I have no idea why it so!

Here is my code. If you have any question, please, write me. I can answer on any question.

```
var tinarr = new List<double>();
        var toutarr = new List<double>();

        tin=RandTime(lambda);
        while (tin > T & tin<=0)
        {
            tin = RandTime(lambda);
        }
        Tin = tin;

        for (double i = step; i <= T; i += step)
        {
            if (Tin > T) break;
            if (Tout > T) break;
            while (Tin <= i)
            {
                if (CarCount < L / l)
                {
                    CarIn++;
                    CarCount++;
                    tinarr.Add(Tin);
                    listBox1.Items.Add("+" + Tin.ToString());

                    //генерация времени выезда для въехавшей машины
                    tout = RandTime(mu);
                    //Tout = 0;
                    Tout += tout;
                    while (Tout <= Tin)
                    {
                        Tout -= tout;
                        tout = RandTime(mu);
                        Tout += tout;
                    }
                    if (toutarr.Count > 0)
                    {
                        while (Tout <= toutarr[0])
                        {
                            Tout -= tout;
                            tout = RandTime(mu);
                            Tout += tout;
                        }
                    }                        
                    if (Tout > T) break;

                    toutarr.Add(Tout);
                    listBox2.Items.Add(Tout.ToString());
                }
                else
                {
                    CarError++;
                    listBox1.Items.Add(Tin.ToString());
                }

                //генерация времени следующей въехавшей машины
                tin = RandTime(lambda);
                Tin += tin;
                if (Tin > T) break;

                //OUT cars
                /* * */
                if (toutarr.Count > 0)
                {
                    for (int j = toutarr.Count - 1; j >= 0; j--)
                    {
                        if (toutarr.Count > 0)
                        {
                            if (toutarr[j] < Tin)
                            {
                                toutarr.RemoveAt(j);
                                CarCount--;
                                CarOut++;
                            }
                        }                            
                    }
                }
                /* ^ */
            }
```

So. Result 1, when programm works not in debug mode. You can see duplicate of digits.

[image: result 1]

Result 2, when it works in debug mode. True results.

[image: result 2]

Comment: We have no idea what your program does. We have no idea what the correct results are. We have no idea what incorrect results you're seeing. It's impossible to help you with so little information. Please read http://tinyurl.com/so-hints

Comment: That's a sure sign that you have corrupted memory and your program needs debugging.

Comment: @Devolus hah, what I should do?

Comment: As I said, you need to debug it and look what it really does as opposed to what you think it does.

Comment: @JonSkeet it's very hard to explain what my programm does. in general, it calculates two arrays of time (I use lists). and programm creates duplicates of digits from one list to another.

Comment: @Maria: Then it's going to be very hard to help you. You need to perform appropriate diagnostics to narrow down the problem until it's something small enough for us to help you - currently your question is the equivalent of saying, "I don't feel very well. What's wrong with me?"

Comment: @Devolus I did it a lot of time and I get true results only in debug mode.

Comment: @JonSkeet Oh, ok. Sorry for worrying.

Comment: @JonSkeet Hi! Can you help me again? I added something

Comment: Is this a simulation of arrivals into a system, in which the arrivals are modeled by Poisson distribution?

Comment: This still isn't a short but complete program. Do you really need it to be in a GUI to start with? A short but complete console app will usually be shorter than one with a GUI.

Comment: @BolucPapuccuoglu yes it is. i hope it is)

Comment: I have a theory. See my answer.

Comment: @Devolus, I think the problem is due to a non-static Random() use

Comment: @JonSkeet , How's that for a Hail Mary? ;-) Pretty slim chance of arriving at the right conclusion from what was given, I think! P.S. reading your book (C# in Depth) now and loving it. Great job!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Okay, I am going to take a shot in the dark here. My guess is that you are using a time based random number generator and instead of generating one instance of it and using the same instance to produce a sample of random numbers, you are re-instantiating the random number generator at each iteration. Now, when the program is not in debug mode, each iteration takes place in the same clock tick (thus providing the same seed to the generator), so that the first number generated by the first call to .Next() of each instance produces the same number. When you enter debug mode and start to step through the code, you are placing a few seconds between each instantiation of the generator, so you provide a different seed for each instance. That way, you see correct results. When you hit continue again, the generators instantiated from that point forward start using the same result, and incorrect behavior re-ensues.

The solution to this is simple. Create ONE random number generator. Make it static to your application. Make all calls to this instance.

Comment: Thank you soooooooooo much!!!!! It works! I didn't thought that problem was in Random function! You have helped me a lot!